# Using the browser context APIs without creating a BrowserWindow in electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm wondering if there is a way to access the browser context APIs in electron without creating a BrowserWindow. Is this feasible somehow?

Comment: It's not a solution, but you can create BrowserWindow with attribute `show` set to `false`. It's not displayed and you can use it's context to do stuff.

Comment: Thanks @AreWojciechowski this is exactly what I ended doing.
I used both the show option and app.dock.hide().
While not perfect, this is pretty close to what I wanted to achieve.